# Reading and writing json file via Nextflow value channels

Tags: json, groovy, nextflow

I have a json file that supplies parameters to a pipeline. The file is parsed and parameters output via some utility methods:

```
class PipelineParameters {
    
    // Function that parses json output file 
    public static Map readParams(json_file) {
        def jsonSlurper = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper()
        String pipelineparameter = new File(json_file).text
        def Map configparam = (Map) jsonSlurper.parseText(pipelineparameter)
        return configparam
    }

    // Function that writes a map to a json file
    public static void writeParams(params, filename) {
        def json = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(params)
        def myFile = new File(filename)
        myFile.write(groovy.json.JsonOutput.prettyPrint(json.toString()))
    }
}
```

After the parameters are read n they are passed to processes via a value channel:

```
parameters = PipelineParameters.readParams(params.pipeline_params)
DoSomething(Channel.fromPath(file), Channel.value(parameters))
```

At the end of the pipeline some parameters may have been changed and I want to output the new parameters using the `writeParams` function. However the call:

```
PipelineParameters.writeParams(parameters.toString(), 'params.json')
```

produces an invalid json i.e.:

```
{data=foo, ncores=40}
```

There are no quotes for example that seem to be required for other json parsers to be able to consume the output file. What am I doing wrong?